# How do I connect a wireless Xbox 360 controller to my Android phone?

Tags: xbox-360, controllers, android

I have:

- Samsung Galaxy S6
- Wireless Xbox 360 Controller
- USB Wireless Adapter for Xbox 360 Controller (Works for Windows/Linux)
- USB OTG Cable (Allows me to plug USB into Android)

I am able to plug the wireless adapter in, and the controller syncs to it, but the controller doesn't appear to function after that.

Comment: How are you testing the functionality of the controller?

Comment: There's a `GamepadTest` App I'm using. iI also try on the home screen to move the selector around (it works for a Playstation 2 Dualshock controller). I should note that I'm using a non-Microsoft wireless adapter that seems to use an older driver set on Windows than the other ones

Comment: I can confirm that if you connect a standard wired 360 controller as you describe (minus the wireless adapter, of course), it will support moving around the home screen, as you describe. Can you confirm if the controller works with the receiver on a computer?

Comment: Yes it works great on a computer. However I need to first install the OLD windows drivers (2010 i think?) in Device manager. The 2015 drivers don't work I don't think.

Comment: did you get this to work? i also have an xbox 360 controller, galaxy s6(rooted) and a wireless receiver.

Comment: Answered here: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/289047/i-want-to-connect-my-wireless-xbox-360-controller-to-my-galaxy-s6-rooted/289054#289054