# I want to connect my wireless xbox 360 controller to my galaxy s6 (rooted)

Tags: xbox-360, controllers, android

So I want to connect my wireless Xbox 360 controller to my rooted galaxy S6, but I don't know how. I have a wireless receiver, an OTG cable and the controller.

Comment: You want it to be wireless or wired works too ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### DISCLAIMER: ROOTING YOUR DEVICE CAN CAUSE ALL SORTS OF TROUBLE. DO ANYTHING TO YOUR DEVICE AT YOUR OWN RISK.

---

That being said, [this forum post](http://www.se7ensins.com/forums/threads/how-to-use-xbox-controllers-on-your-android-device.882265/?jdfwkey=cvtic3) pretty much sums up all you need to be able to connect an Xbox 360 controller to it. To surmise:

Although you already have all the things required, I'll list them out here for the sake of completeness:

- Xbox 360 controller
- Wireless Reciever
- OTG Cable
- Rooted Device (it needs to be rooted if you want to use the wireless controller)

### Setting Up:

From the aforementioned forum post:

> 1. Plug Xbox 360 Wireless Controller Receiver into OTG cable
> 2. Plug OTG cable into device
>
> Now comes the fun bit. Wireless controllers aren't naturally supported
> by android and will not work flawlessly without modification to some
> system files on your device. Many emulators and games will run
> perfectly happily simply on a plug-n-play basis but an issue presents
> itself often where this is not the case. Wireless controllers require
> calibration if you will to properly communicate with your Android
> device.
>
> This is where root is needed. You need to access the Android shell and
> enter some commands to fix this problem. Once into the shell (using an
> app such as Terminal Emulator) enter the following commands:

```
su
cd /system/usr/keylayout/
mount -o remount,rw /system
cp Vendor_045e_Product_0291.kl Vendor_045e_Product_0719.kl
chmod 644 Vendor_045e_Product_0291.kl
chmod 644 Vendor_045e_Product_0719.kl
exit
exit
```

> Then restart your device and your wireless controller should work
> fine. Remember that different devices will function differently and
> this may have no effect on your device.

All of this is just a summary, and for a more detailed explanation I urge you to gather more info before making any modifications to your device.

- [Connect Xbox 360 Controller to Android Phone/Tablet (Video)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mSS5WSi75Kk)
- [How To Connect a Game Controller to Android For Console-like Gameplay](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-connect-a-game-controller-to-android-for-console-like-gameplay-si/)
- [How to use Xbox controllers on your Android device](http://www.se7ensins.com/forums/threads/how-to-use-xbox-controllers-on-your-android-device.882265/?jdfwkey=cvtic3)

Comment: Hi @Despato, in case you're monitoring it and know by any chance?

I've followed all steps I've found online and my Android device still doesn't recognize the controller. Would you know why that could be? Ta   https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/395352/unable-to-have-wired-xbox-360-style-controllers-recognized-by-android-5-samsung