# How can I connect my wireless Xbox 360 controller to my Galaxy Tab 3 8.4?

Tags: xbox-360, controllers, android

I tried to follow [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/289054/83392) solution, but the problem is that my device is a Galaxy Tab 3, not a Galaxy S6.

I am connecting the receiver to the tablet using an OTG cable (which works, because I tried a mouse with it). The XBOX 360 wireless controller is just not pairing up with the receiver, the lights keeps flashing.

The problem with the solution I tried is that I cannot run the command:

```
cp Vendor_045e_Product_0291.kl Vendor_045e_Product_0719.kl
```

Because the file `Vendor_045e_Product_0291.kl` does not exist. There are files with similar names but I don't know which one I have to copy and probably even it needs a different renaming... I don't know. Does anyone know which file I need to use?

Or is there an easier solution?

Comment: It would help to know why the question is downvoted :(

Comment: Many moons ago I had this problem on PC, and I found [this article](http://www.wtflolomgbbq.com/Blog/tabid/84/EntryId/2/Xbox-360-Controller-Wireless-PC-Adapter-drivers.aspx) with drivers that helped me.  This won't help you on Android - but I would suggest trying your adapter on a PC to make sure it works.  I got 2, and one was DOA out of the box.  All the software in the world won't fix that.

Comment: Oh, it definitively works on PC :(

Comment: Do you see the light come on the XBox 360 receiver when you plug it in?  Sorry for the lame question, but you did press the button on the receiver to initiate syncing to the controller, right?

Comment: Yes I see the light. Y press the sync button in the receiver and in the controller. When pressed in only one of them, the light starts flashing/spinning. When pressed in the second one the lights come back to its natural state (steady in the receiver, flashing in the controller) So it is paired up. I am just missing the drivers.

Answer (score 5):

The answer you linked is giving the instructions for people to copy a [*KeyLayout*](https://source.android.com/devices/input/key-layout-files) file (`Vendor_045e_Product_0291.kl`) to another file (`Vendor_045e_Product_0719.kl`), so that the Operating System can match the *product ID*<sup>1</sup> of your device against the KeyLayout file intended for an older (but compatible) version of the device.

However, the description of your problem isn't enough to give a conclusive answer.

From what I know, the controller will be able to work with an Android device even though it is not visually "pairing" (as indicated by the LEDs around the XBox button).

To connect to your controller, the android device will require an existing driver in the first place.

**So the first thing you should do** is plug it, follow the steps you have followed the first time you connected your controller to your computer<sup>2</sup>, and then try the controller out. This will help you determine if there is a driver present for the device: If yes, using it should allow to change the selection of your icons on your desktop, or at least have a visual effect upon activation. Else, chances are that you are missing the driver for the XBox controller; which is a much more difficult file to find than a configuration file (such as a KeyLayout file).

---

**In case you are missing a driver**:

Drivers need to fit your hardware (architecture, devices) and software (kernel, possibly libraries). You usually cannot transfer them around between devices and have them *"just work"*. If you miss a driver, you will need to get one that matches the exact same android version and the exact same hardware (i.e one precisely for your controller)

So, short of finding a pre-compiled driver for your device somewhere, you would need to find the source code for this driver and compile it yourself; which isn't an easy task<sup>3</sup> and then, even if you have the sources, you would need to compile them, probably without documentation or assistance, which will certainly prove challenging.

You however have a few options to try, before giving up, if you are missing the Xbox controller driver for your Galaxy Tab:

1. Find a compatible driver on your device and copy (or symlink) it to the right folder/file for the driver. Then add it to the modules loaded at boot time.
2. Find a compatible driver on a similar device (same list of drivers as in the previous point; but this can be tricky since it is a differing device, and will involve a lot of trial and error) and perform the operations described in the previous point.
3. Find the source code for the driver (or a reverse-engineered version of it) and try compiling it until you succeed (Good luck!)
4. Find assistance in some android development boards (XDA, etc.) or chats (the IRC channel of LineageOS - formerly known as Cyanogenmod) to learn how to solve this problem yourself.

Note that I tried to sort those options in an ascending time cost manner, so that the first ones should yield a (positive or not) result faster.

Also, an important note is that I was told on the LineageOS IRC channel that it is usually easier to re-build the whole image for a device than to add a driver to it.

---

**In case you are just missing the KeyLayout file**:

If your controller "sort of" works but you are getting unwanted behavior with it, you are most probably missing a KeyLayout file.

This is the problem that corresponds to the solution you are describing in your question.

However, you cannot take a random KeyLayout file, copy it over with the `Vendor_045e_Product_0719.kl`<sup>4</sup> name, and expect it to work.

The file that you would copy to `Vendor_045e_Product_0719.kl` should match the configuration of your input device, or it will not solve the problem of having an inconsistent input. (`Vendor_045e_Product_0291.kl` should such a file, since it is for the XBox 360 Wireless Controller, but maybe there are others: search (on your favorite search engine - a quick search gave me [`045E:02A1`](https://usb-ids.gowdy.us/read/UD/045e), and maybe also [`045E:028F`](https://usb-ids.gowdy.us/read/UD/045e)) what *ProductID* the Xbox 360 controllers can have, to get the full list).

You can also attempt to create the missing KeyLayout file by following the [process described here](http://www.thriveforums.org/forum/toshiba-thrive-development/9626-how-create-customized-keylayout-any-usb-bluetooth-keyboard-rooted.html).

In any case, if your controller is recognized but has the wrong behavior, it is a much easier problem to solve.

---

Footnotes:

1. When using USB connections (but not only), devices are [identified with a *Vendor ID* and a *Product ID*, each being four hexadecimal characters long](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_driver#Identifiers) - or 2 bytes - and usually written down like: `XXXX:YYYY` where `XXXX` is the vendor ID and `YYYY` is the product ID. In your case that would give `045E:0291` and `045E:0719` (`045E` is a vendorID from Microsoft).
2. First press the button on the receiver to set it to "pairing mode" and then press the paring button on the controller - and do not worry about the LEDs flashing, it may keep doing that, yet work.
3. Finding the sources for a proprietary technology from Microsoft isn't usually easy - and if you find some sources, they will probably be unofficial sources written via reverse-engineering (so they may have issues and glitches).
4. While possible, it is **NOT GUARANTEED** that the `045E:0719` hardware identifier is the one of your device. If it is not, you will need to find the correct hardware identifier before continuing. To find out if it is, use `lsusb` on GNU/Linux or [the Microsoft® Windows™ Device Manager](http://www.wikihow.com/Find-Hardware-ID) while plugging your XBox 360 Wireless Receiver to your computer.

Comment: I am missing the driver. The controller is not recognised. Could you elaborate more in your following solution? "Find a compatible driver on your device and copy (or symlink) it to the right folder/file for the driver. Then add it to the modules loaded at boot time."

Comment: I am not a driver expert, but for what it is worth there is a walk through on compiling xpad.ko from Ubuntu [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Xbox360Controller) and also a user space driver called xboxdrv [here](https://pingus.seul.org/~grumbel/xboxdrv/).  It would seem that your version of Android should already have native support though...

Comment: @EBongo The android system is wildly different (the [libc for example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bionic_%28software%29)) from usual GNU/Linux systems such as Ubuntu. Compiling and installing software for GNU/Linux is orders of magnitude easier (there more tools, the process is more documented, etc.) than installing software on Android. If David goes that route, I suspect it will be a long (but interesting) process that won't yield the expected result easily, nor any time soon. So in that case he should definitely go on IRC/XDA.

Comment: @DavidTorres How do you tell that you are missing the driver? Did you try to use the controller while the LED still blinks?

Comment: @7heo.tk Agreed, I am a computer scientist and still I will pass. The effort-reward is not good here. I tried using the controller (with a tester app, games, and it is supposed to mover through the icon pages with the joystick). So yes, I tried to use it even if it is blinking (I know in android it doesn't stop blinking even when it works fine)

Comment: @DavidTorres The debugging necessary for your issue involves trial and error, as well as advanced knowledge of the android system. For this reason, I would really recommend that you go on XDA/IRC if you wish to make progress. I unfortunately see no obvious easy solution so far (there might be one, but it will anyway require probing to know what's amiss, if anything).