# Unable to have wired Xbox 360 style controllers recognized by Android 5 (Samsung Galaxy Note Pro 12.2)

Tags: xbox-360, controllers, android

I've got the Samsung Note Pro tablet on the latest android 5.0.2

I've got 2 gamepads which work on the Xbox 360 and when I try to use them on the tablet none of them are recognized.

I've followed all guides I've found around in this and other sites talking about the subject and:

- I've got a root device
- I've been able to find the Vendor and ProdID of both by looking into `/sys/kernel/debug/usb/devices'

  - both of the USB wired controllers appear there

    - gamepad 1 = vendor 0738, prodID 4738
    - gamepad 2 = vendor 1bad, prodID f025
- So I've created the following files with the config of an Xbox 360 controller:

  - /system/usr/keylayout/Vendor_0738_Product_4738.kl
  - /system/usr/keylayout/Vendor_1bad_Product_f025.kl
- Just in case, I tried with and without the following too:

  - /system/usr/keychars/Vendor_0738_Product_4738.kcm
  - /system/usr/keychars/Vendor_1bad_Product_f025.kcm
- All of those have the right 644 rw-r--r-- permissions

After all changes, rebooting and reconnecting... still, none of the 2 controllers are recognized by this Android tablet.

I checked the following with each of them plugged in, and they were not appearing as connected:

- /proc/bus/input/devices

Any idea what the problem could be?
Or what else could I try? Most guides talk about the .kl files above and they say it should work, but in this case, it doesn't... any other suggestion?

Ta

Comment: Which app are you trying to use them in? 0738:4738 is "Mad Catz Wired Xbox 360 Controller (SFIV)" and 1BAD:F025 is "Mad Catz Call Of Duty", both have been supported by xpad for years so I'd expect them to work correctly without a keylayout file.

Comment: @nondebug, the main one I want, where it doesn't appear as recognized is `RetroArch`, but I've tried several other `game tester` apps from play store and they don't recognized them either. And checking the values in `/proc/bus/input/devices` none of them appear as connected there. 

As for the keylayout files, those 2 vendors/productIds were not appearing for me, so just in case I put them. but still no luck. 

Do you have any other idea that I could try?